# How to use Powerapps for Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I was using Infopath earlier to edit sharepoint site, but now our organization restricted to use infopath and advised to move on to Power apps.

Comment: Hello ! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please make a clear and understandable question: the clearer it is, the more users will be pleased to help you !

Answer (score 0):

Power Apps can use SharePoint On-Premise data through a connection gateway, see articles below:

- https://jwcooney.com/2017/05/28/set-up-microsoft-powerapps-to-connect-to-an-on-premises-sharepoint-installation/
- https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connect-to-your-on-premises-data-sources-using-on-premises-data-gateway-from-powerapps/
- https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/support-for-sharepoint-on-premises/
- https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

So the apps created with the Power Apps Studio will run from the Power Apps Server while using data from your SharePoint 2016 environment through a connection gateway.  The same is also true for Flow.